# Full screen coverage using the FlowingDrawer Android library

Tags: java

I'm using the FlowingDrawer library
But there is a problem
When running, FlowingDrawer covers the entire mobile launcher and no options can be selected.

This means that when the program is running, I can not select an option and it is as if a page covers the entire content (like when a transparent is used as a background)

- FlowingDrawer runs but the whole page crashes and no option can be selected
  What way do you suggest to solve this problem ?!
  I hope I have clarified what I mean
  Grateful

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQIbw.png)

```
<com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingDrawer
                    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:edPosition="1"
                    app:edMenuSize="260dp"
                    app:edMenuBackground="#dddddd">

                    <!--content-->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/fl_main"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <!--menu-->
                    <com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingMenuLayout
                        android:id="@+id/menulayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/id_container_menu"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="200dp"
                                android:id="@+id/header">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/imgChannelCoverDrawer"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:src="@drawable/bg_card_video_main"/>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/CircleImageChannelProfileDrawer"
                                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                                        android:src="@drawable/image_placeholder"
                                        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
                                        app:layout_anchor="@id/mainAppBar"
                                        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:text="انیمیشن بی مغز"
                                        android:textSize="28sp"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/yekan"
                                        android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/li_home"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                                android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="48dp" >
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/home_24"
                                    android:padding="4dp"
                                    app:tint="@color/cardview_dark_background"/>
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="صفحه اصلی"
                                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/yekan"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"
                                    android:padding="4dp"/>
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/li_share"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/li_home"
                                android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="24dp" >
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/share_24"
                                    android:padding="4dp"
                                    app:tint="@color/cardview_dark_background" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="اشتراک گذاری"
                                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/yekan"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"
                                    android:padding="4dp"/>
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/li_about"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/li_share"
                                android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="24dp" >
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/person_outline_24"
                                    android:padding="4dp"
                                    app:tint="@color/cardview_dark_background" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="درباره ما"
                                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/yekan"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"
                                    android:padding="4dp"/>
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/li_logout"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/li_about"
                                android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="24dp" >
                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_power_settings_new_24"
                                    android:padding="4dp"
                                    app:tint="@color/cardview_dark_background" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="خروج از برنامه"
                                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/yekan"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"
                                    android:padding="4dp"/>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingMenuLayout>

                </com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingDrawer>
```

Comment: I solved the problem